NotifierProvider being set without executing the code in Flutter app
I have a flutter web app where I set a global variable, companyID, in a global notifier provider when the user successfully logs in.
In the first line of code below, I set the global variable, newUser, to "false".
In the last line of code in the snippet below, I update the global variable, companyId. However, when this line of code executes, newUser gets set to "true". I don't know why or how this is happening. I have set a breakpoint in the code where I set the newUser variable but that code doesn't get executed.
Here is the login code:
ref.read(globalsNotifierProvider.notifier).updatenewUser(false);
final DocumentSnapshot _currentUserProfile =
    await usersRef.doc(globals.currentUid).get();

if (_currentUserProfile != null) {
  ///
  /// Update the global provider
  ///
  ref
      .read(globalsNotifierProvider.notifier)
      .updatecompanyId(_currentUserProfile.get('companyId'));

In the code above, I set the newUser variable to "false" because this is not a new user.
However, in this line of code below, the newUser variable gets set to "true".
  ref
      .read(globalsNotifierProvider.notifier)
      .updatecompanyId(_currentUserProfile.get('companyId'));

Why is this happening?
Thanks in advance

You definitely are missing some example code. But I bet, your provider is autodispose and gets reset between observations.

Thanks for your comment. I didn't know anything about the autodispose so I read about it and I didn't add autodispose anywhere. Maybe it is set by default but I have not had this problem anywhere else in the code and this just started. I will keep looking but I have a workaround for now.
